# Nodejs partial view Error

Tags: node.js, partial-views, pug

I am a Nodejs beginner,I use `jade` template engine .I want to render the partial view and the view code is :

```
extends layout

block content
h1= title
p Welcome to
p #{title}
- partial('p')
```

But when I start the site,I got the Error:

```
500 TypeError: /home/hxh/share/nodejs/microblog/views/index.jade:7<br/> 5| p Welcome   to<br/> 6| p #{title}<br/> > 7| - partial('p')<br/> 8| 
undefined is not a   function
5| p Welcome to
6| p #{title}
> 7| - partial('p')
```

Who can tell me why the Error raise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be basing your jade sample code on some old examples.  I'm assuming in line 7 you are wanting to include a html snippet from a file called 'p'.  Partials don't exist in the latest version of Jade, you should use the "include" keyword instead (https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/0.33.0#includes)